# CSS not applying in my DRUPAL 7 site on localhost

Tags: css, drupal, drupal-7, localhost

I'm working with Drupal 7.2, till now i have worked on somebody's localhost,now i decided to work on my own PC, so i make a copy of original code form other's PC and paste it to my localhost WAMP and also upload database into my **localhost/phpmyadmin**, but some how its not working at all.

CSS not been applying to the site, its displaying all the content without CSS. can anyone help me for this issue?

**I tried out by clearing a cache from admin side as well as from browser.**

Thanks.

Comment: Note there is also a [drupal-site](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/) on stackexchange.

Comment: Have you checked the paths in your themes.info file?

Comment: Does Drupal status shoes you any errors?

Comment: @SpaceBeers & Vlad srtatulat: i have checked path and no error displayed.

Comment: Hhmm. Hard to say without seeing any code. If you go to view source what is the path to your CSS?

Comment: You've likely got CSS/JS aggregation on and haven't set the folder `/sites/default/files` to be owned/writeable by the web server since the site moved. Give your web server 775 permissions over `/sites/default/files` and you should be good to go

Answer (score 3):

Not just the cache but the aggregating too make sure you clear all the check boxes
 Cache pages for anonymous users 
 Cache blocks 
Even those under bandwidth optimization
 Aggregate and compress CSS files. 
 Aggregate JavaScript files. 
Works like a charm. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you're seeing the Drupal site itself (implying your db/web server/php settings are ok) but just unthemed? Have you tried clearing the Drupal caches? As you lifted the database from another host it's possible you might need to do this to force drupal to rebuild it's menu paths.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the source code of the site on your localhost and check that the file paths to the css style sheets is correct. Using Google Chrome Developer Tool you can update the paths and see when they take affect or just keep updating your templates until you get it right. Also check that any options in the database are using your localhost and not the other domain

Answer (score 1):

You may try following to debug:

1. Clear Drupal cache from admin/settings/performance.
2. Rebuild theme registry.
3. Add a new theme to your site and see if it is rendering the content properly.

Answer (score 1):

I see the same problem, yet no solution suggested has resolved this... I notice in source code that it seems to truncate the css paths to be at site root i.e. < link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://dev.drupalsite.com/installed_dir/ media="all" > ... hmm